# HTML, CSS unselectable image doesn't work

Tags: html, css, web

I have created a website where my navigation buttons consist of images, as seen in the code below. Now if I go on my website and click & drag the button, it will drag like in the picture below(red circle). I do not want my buttons to do that. I want them to sit there and only be clickable, but not selectable & dragable or saved on their(viewers) computer.

This dragable image is a "phantom" image, it's not actually moving the button around.

```
<div class="top unselectable">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html"><img src="images/home2.png" class="menu" width="218" height="50" ></a></li>
    <li><a href="ps.html"><img src="images/ps2.png" class="menu" width="218" height="50" ></a></li>
    <li><a href="ae.html"><img src="images/ae2.png" class="menu" width="218" height="50" ></a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html"><img src="images/contact.png" class="menu" width="218" height="50" ></a></li>
    </ul> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.top.unselectable {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

[image]

Comment: your code is working for me - http://jsfiddle.net/fn106a4j/

Comment: What exactly do you mean by unselectable?

Comment: I want the navigation bar, aka images(home2.png etc) to be "undragable" or unselectable. I don't want people to be able to drag them.

Comment: I have updated my post with a screenshot!

Comment: double check your browser and version to see if it's supported. Also according to this site, `user-select` is not well supported and is buggy: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/u/user-select/

Comment: Tried it in Firefox and Chrome. I have the latest versions.

Comment: Please provide further details on what you are trying to achieve. Not your actual exptected solution. HTML elements are not drag and droppable on a page. Sure I can take an element and drag it around the page, but without further work it will not drop or "stick" anywhere on the page. You can drag elements to copy them into a document etc. It that the behaviour your are trying to stop?

Comment: I'm going to follow this up with: Why? Do you evidence that your users are trying to drag thins around the page? I would not expect this to be a common behavior. You may end up spending a lot of time trying to solve a problem that in reality effects a very small number of users as I can't think of a CSS way to stop the "phantom" drag behavior and a javascript solution would not be trivial and easily circuvented. What are the consequenses of users copying your nav images in that  way? If they really want them the will be able to get them.

Comment: Also check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select. Note the big block of red at the top: **This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.**